# Do any action if variable into interval function has value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got small problem with my script

She looks like this:

```js
i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
 
 if(i < 100) {
  i++;
 }
 
}, 1000);

if(i == 100) {
  alert("done");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But alert doesn't work after incrementing to 100. Why? How can i do that?

Comment: The `alert()` call will have to be **inside** the interval handler, and it should also cancel the timer.

Comment: setInterval is asynchronous, so `if(i == 100)` is checked first before even incrementing it to 100. so, put that checking code inside setInterval.

Comment: You may have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop

Answer (score 3):

Because of `if(i < 100)` that says untill the i is 99 or less.

If you need to increment till 100 use `if(i <= 100)` which is 100 or less.

Answer (score 0):

When `if(i == 100)` condition is executed the value of `i` is 0, which is incremented inside the setInterval function but no way `if(i == 100)` knows that.So put this condition inside the setTimeout function

```js
var i = 0;

var _int = setInterval(function() {

  if (i < 100) {
    i++;
  }
  if (i == 100) {
    alert("done");
    clearInterval(_int)
  }

}, 40);
```